# NullPointerException error with Rendering

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, lang

I am getting this error whenever I press spacebar(to shoot the 'missile'), and I can't find out how to fix it, at all.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.game.main.Bullet.render(Bullet.java:26)
    at com.game.main.Controller.render(Controller.java:58)
    at com.game.main.Game.render(Game.java:155)
    at com.game.main.Game.run(Game.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I will list the code that is in the error as I have 9 classes.

The `Bullet` error line:

```
g.drawImage(tex.missile, (int)x, (int)y, null);
```

`tex.missile` is a `BufferedImage` variable from the texture class, and is set to

```
missile = ss.grabImage(2, 1, 32, 32);
```

`ss` is a `SpriteSheet` class and is set to `new SpriteSheet(game.getSpriteSheet());`

The `SpriteSheet` class just gets the `SpriteSheet` and just sets each square to a row/column etc. Everything there works as my Player & Enemy both work.

Controller error line:

```
tempBullet.render(g);
```

Game.render error line:

```
c.render(g);
```

Game.run error line:

```
render();
```

I highly doubt it has anything to do with the `Game` class, or anything like that, but I think it has to do with the `Bullet` class, but yet again. I could be, and most likely am wrong. I think that something may not be set correctly.

**If you want me to show a whole class, I will. Just tell me which one you need.**

**EDIT:** g.drawImage is inside of this method

```
public void render(Graphics g){ 
    g.drawImage(tex.missile, (int)x, (int)y, null);
}
```

Comment: What type is `g` when you call `g.drawImage(...)`?

Comment: Test if one of these is null: `g`, `tex`, `x` or `y` (x and y can be null if you use wrapper classes like `Integer`).

Comment: @GuntherFox Most likely a `Graphics` instance: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29

Comment: You need to show the cause of the error. More importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me. So find out what's null and let us know. My guess -- you're using a `getGraphics()` call on a component to get your Graphics object, and Graphics, g, is null

Comment: @Tom I will do now, I'll get back to you when I've checked :)

Comment: Please show enough code so that we can understand your problem.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I checked and tex was null, in my constructor, I just had to define tex, so I did this.tex = tex; and it works now, thankyou!

Comment: If anyone wants to put an answer then I'd be happy to tick it :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thankyou too! Helped me find out which Variable is null, helped alot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` occurs if you're trying to perform an action (like a method call) on a `null` reference.
So if you're getting this exception on this line `g.drawImage(tex.missile, (int)x, (int)y, null);`, then check if one of the following variables is `null`:

- `g`
- `tex`
- `x`
- `y`

`x` and `y` can be null, if you use a wrapper class like `Integer`. The provided `null` reference for the image observer (forth argument of the method `drawImage`) won't cause a `NullPointerException`, so there is no need to change something there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @xenteros I know (now; this answer is 2 years old), but this answer has been accepted and I can't delete it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To give a precie answer, a wider description would be necessary, i.e. what framework you are using etc.. From what you write I assume the following:

- You're writing in Java.
- You're working on a game.
- You're using some renderer to render something.

Did you write that renderer yourself? Are you using a framework? What platform are you actually targeting?

This might already help you:
I'd guess that "g" hasn't been initialized or is just set to null. Try setting a breakpoint before the line where your code crashes, run the debugger and see what "g" contains. If it does not point to null, the problem might be somewhere else. Also note that you're passing "null" as the last parameter, which might not be allowed here. ;)